# Is zeroconf (Bonjour, Avahi) able to speak IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

Or does it mean only for autoconfiguration of hosts in ipv4 based networks?
Could it work to use zeroconf in a IPv6-only network?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ZeroConf works for both IPv4 and IPv6.

ZeroConf has 3 main parts. Here's a summary of how they work with IPv6:

1. **Link-local addressing.** IPv6 actually does this much better than IPv4. Every IPv6 capable network interface always has a self-assigned link-local address even if it also has a publicly routable IPv6 addresss. IPv6 link-local addresses start with `fe80:`.
2. **Multicast DNS name resolution (mDNS).** mDNS uses the same packet format as traditional unicast DNS, so it supports v6 the same way DNS does. When you want to know the v6 address of a given hostname, you ask for its AAAA record.
3. **DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD).** This didn't have to change much at all for IPv6. You just send the same kind of [m]DNS queries and responses over IPv6 instead of IPv4.